# show a list of fields based on selection first field

Tags: python, html, django

I have 2 classes and I´d like to show a list of fields from the second class based on the first class. For example:

servico:

```
id  desc_servico
1   teste1
2   teste2
```

itemservico:

```
id desc_itemservico servico
1  itemteste1        1
2  itemteste2        2
```

In this example, if I choose servico=1, the itemservico has to show me itemteste1. If I choose servico=2, the itemservico has to show itemteste2.

Models.py:

```
class servico(models.Model):
    desc_servico = models.CharField('Descrição', max_length=50, default='', blank=False, null=False)

class itemservico(models.Model):
    desc_itemservico = models.CharField('Descrição', max_length=50, default='', blank=False, null=False)
    val_itemservico = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    servico = models.ForeignKey(servico, default='', blank=True, null=True)  # Chave estrangeira da Classe Serviço
    ind_selecionado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py:

```
class itemservicoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    servico = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=servico.objects.all().order_by('desc_servico'), empty_label="Serviço")

    class Meta:
        model = itemservico
        fields = (
                    'servico',
                  )
```

template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ORÇAMENTO</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>ORÇAMENTO</h2>

    <form class=" bd-form-20 " action="" name="form-name" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <label class="bd-form-label" >Serviço  </label>{{form.servico}}<br><br>
        <p><h1>{{form.servivo.id}}</h1></p>

          <div class=" bd-customhtml-29 bd-tagstyles bd-custom-table">
            <div class="bd-container-inner bd-content-element">
              <table border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <th>Testar</th>
                    <th>Selecionar</th>
                    <th>ID Item Serviço</th>
                    <th>Item Serviço</th>
                    <th>Valor Serviço</th>
                    <th>Serviço</th>
                </tr>

                {% for item in instance_itens %}
                <tr>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="item.ind_selecionado"></td>
                        <td>{{ item.ind_selecionado }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.desc_itemservico }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.val_itemservico }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.servico_id}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>

              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

    </form>

    <br><br>
    <button class="bd-linkbutton-60  bd-button  bd-own-margins bd-content-element"  type = "submit" >
    OK</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you want to do.. can you explain more? You have two models, and want to see both fields from two models in your form?

Comment: if you have an object `servico` you can get all the `itemservico` linked to it by the foreign key using `servico.itemservico_set.all` within your template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use Ajax post for generating results based on selection.

for view.py part you need use this function:

```
def ajax_post(request):
if request.POST:
    if request.POST.get('servico') and request.is_ajax():
        itemservico_list = itemservico.objects.filter(servico = request.POST.get('servico'))
        return render_to_response('itemservico.html',{'itemservico_list':itemservico_list})
```

For Html part you need to generate itemservico.html seperated and include it to main html such as

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<tbody><tr>
<th>Testar</th>
<th>Selecionar</th>
<th>ID Item Serviço</th>
<th>Item Serviço</th>
<th>Valor Serviço</th>
<th id='targetselection'>Serviço</th>
</tr>
<div id='inner'>
{% include "itemservico.html" %}
</div>
</tbody>
</form>
```

And you need to create another html file for itemservico such as

```
{% for item in itemservico_list %}
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox" id="item.ind_selecionado"></td>
<td>{{ item.ind_selecionado }}</td>
<td>{{ item.id }}</td>
<td>{{ item.desc_itemservico }}</td>
<td>{{ item.val_itemservico }}</td>
<td>{{ item.servico_id}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

For JS part you need to create a js file for which detect state changes or key press of any given field: (I use jquery for selection)

```
$('#targetselection').on('change keyup paste', function() { 
    servico = $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
    ajaxPost(servico);
});

function ajaxPost(query){
  $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:token,
                servico : servico
            },
            dataType:'html',
            success:function (data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            $('#inner').html(data);
            }
        });
}
```

As a summary: When some selection changes on the web site, its creating an ajax request on server. As a view part you are filtering data according to ajax post request. Rendering html file and pushing it into specific part of web page. I hope this would be helpfull

Comment: Thank you but it´s very complicated. I got it in a easy way, with Filterset.

Comment: {% for item in response.object_list %}
                <tr>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="item.ind_selecionado"></td>
                        <td>{{ item.ind_selecionado }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.desc_itemservico }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.val_itemservico }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.servico_id}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

Comment: Right now i need to sum val_itemservico column when ind_selecionado field be checked.

Comment: I think is better to close this ticket and open a new one. Thanks.